# Undefined index : Laravel

Tags: laravel

Undefined index: SID

How to fix it and what does this mean?

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Student([
        'SID'   => $row["SID"],
        'fname' => $row["fname"],
        'lname' => $row["lname"],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: add a dd($row) on tom of the return and check what values the array param contains

Comment: The error  is saying that `$row` (the array passed to the method) doesn't contain `SID`. Please can you show how you're calling this method and also what data you're passing to it.

Comment: Try once `$row->SID,` like this

Comment: model : student protected $table = 'studentdetails';

 protected $fillable = [
    'SID','fname','lname'

Comment: index $data = Student::latest()->paginate(10);

Answer (score -1):

Please use `Arr::get` or `data_get` to solve this issue.